# text displayed outside of <div> when parent position is relative

Tags: css, html

I have this title bar `<div>` that contains some text. The position of the `<div>` is all working fine but but for some weird reason the text inside it is completely outside the `<div>` as follows in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXW9e/4/) code.
I seriously have tried everything but I just can't find out why this text is there. It may have something with the floating `<div>`'s above or the parent element (the `<div>`) being set to:

```
div#user_topics_box {
    position: relative;
    top: 134px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

But I still don't understand how that is affecting the inner text. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
The text is supposed to be inside the first black bar div above it.

Comment: Where should it appear than?

Comment: in the black bar above it.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/Ka6f5/1/show/ ?

Comment: If you specify the CSS property `position:relative` to the parent element and `position:absolute` to the child element, you can then re position the child relative to its parent using `top:50px; left:50px bottom:10px or right:50px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ka6f5/1/show/
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

You need to clear the floated containers preceding.

```
#user_topics_box {
  clear: both;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 134px;
}
```

And make the floated containers to be contained in the parent container

```
#profile_area {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto` or `clear:left` to `.infobox`:

```
.infobox {
    border-right:2px inset #888;
    border-left:2px inset #888;
    border-bottom:2px inset #888;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NXW9e/6/)** (overflow)

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lpx5Y/)** (clear)

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the float on `#user_topics_title` with something like `clear: both;`.
On your `#user_topics_box` you should set `top: 0;` and adjust the `height` to whatever fits your needs.

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXW9e/7/).